# Haskell speed issue where executing both parts of a program takes significantly longer than either part alone

Tags: performance, haskell, ghc

I have a Haskell program which has 2 lines of code in the main:

```
putStrLn $ "Day11: part1: " ++ show (sum $ bigManhattan 1 galaxies <$> pairs)
putStrLn $ "Day11: part2: " ++ show (sum $ bigManhattan 999999 galaxies <$> pairs)
```

If I comment out **either one of them** the program runs in 0.01s. With both of them extant the program takes 90s.

I wonder if anyone has any ideas? Could they be competing to look at the data and getting in each others way?

Compiler options - I don't know what most of these do...

```
ghc-options:
- -Wall
- -Wcompat
- -Widentities
- -Wincomplete-record-updates
- -Wincomplete-uni-patterns
- -Wmissing-export-lists
- -Wmissing-home-modules
- -Wpartial-fields
- -Wredundant-constraints
- -O2
```

The code:

```
module Day11(day11) where

import Data.List ((\\))
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)


type Coord = (Int, Int)


manhattan :: Coord -> Coord -> Int
manhattan (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = abs (x1 - x2) + abs (y1 - y2)


getF :: (String -> a) -> Int -> IO a
getF f n = do
  s <- readFile $ "./Data/Day" ++ show n ++ ".in"
  return $ f s


getLines :: Int -> IO [String]
getLines = getF lines


parse :: [String] -> [Coord]
parse css = concatMap (catMaybes . (\(y, cs) -> (\(x, c) -> if c=='#' then Just (x,y) else Nothing) <$> zip [0..] cs)) (zip [0..] css)


nSize :: Int
nSize = 140


bigManhattan :: Int -> [Coord] -> (Coord, Coord) -> Int
bigManhattan k galaxies ((c1, r1), (c2, r2)) = manhattan (c1+newc1, r1+newr1) (c2+newc2, r2+newr2)
  where
    baseC, baseR :: [Int]
    baseC = [0..(nSize-1)] \\ (fst <$> galaxies)
    baseR = [0..(nSize-1)] \\  (snd <$> galaxies)
    newc1, newc2, newr1, newr2 :: Int
    newc1 = k * length (filter (c1>) baseC)
    newc2 = k * length (filter (c2>) baseC)
    newr1 = k * length (filter (r1>) baseR)
    newr2 = k * length (filter (r2>) baseR)


day11 :: IO ()
day11 = do
  ls <- getLines 11
  let galaxies = parse ls
      pairs = [(x,y) | x <- galaxies, y <- galaxies, x<y ]

  putStrLn $ "Day11: part1: " ++ show (sum $ bigManhattan 1 galaxies <$> pairs)
  --putStrLn $ "Day11: part2: " ++ show (sum $ bigManhattan 999999 galaxies <$> pairs)
  return ()
```

Using GHC 9.4.7.

Comment: please post a minimal reproducible example. we don't know what `bigManhattan`, `galaxies` and `pairs` are and how much data they contain.

Comment: but most likely, since haskell is lazily evaluated, your program actually doesn't do anything if you comment out those two lines. see e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness

Comment: What compilation arguments are you using? Does it take a noticeably different time to compile the fast and the slow version?

Comment: And what are the contents of the Day11.in input file (in function `getF`) ?

Comment: Code added. There are 452 galaxies, so about 100k pairs in my data file.

Comment: The input file is https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/11/input

Comment: One solution I've found is to make another version of bigManhattan which used a Set of galaxies instead of a list - and then calling the list version for part one and the set version for part 2.

Comment: Got my own input file from AOC web site. FWIW I reproduced the problem on my machine. Interesting !

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. Running both parts takes ~90 s and running either part alone takes ~45 s. I am using  ghc 9.6.3 with -O2 (didn't bother with the other options).

Comment: I reproduced the problem with GHC v8.10.7 and -O2 as sole option.

Comment: @jpmarinier Tried various versions of ghc on godbolt, all of them error out with "processing time exceeded", nothing close to 0.01s. https://godbolt.org/z/b4x91339j

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI  @b1g3ar5 - Looking at that whole thing from a Fortran viewpoint, one notes that function `bigManhattan` recomputes needlessly at every call from galaxies both baseC and baseR. I made a `bigManhattan2` function that receives from caller both baseC and baseR instead of galaxies. With that change, the overall runtime gets below one second for k=1 AND k=999999. Problem sort of solved, but some Haskell mystery remains.

Comment: @jpmarinier Based on your suggestion - I tried passing just unzip galaxies rather than galaxies and it slows down to 45s for each individual call! Weird - it must have to do with how the lists are compiled/optimised.

Comment: Does memory usage of the program increase linearly while it's running? If so, I'd try to add some strictness annotations. (Or I suppose checking whether the code can be tail-call-eliminated never hurts...)

Comment: @mb21 Memory starts at 6 MB, grows to about 15 MB till the first result gets printed, then remains essentially constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `baseC` and `baseR` depend on `galaxies` but not the `pairs`.  When you print only one of the two results, GHC inlines all of `bigManhattan` and is able to lift `baseC` and `baseR` out of the `sum`.  But, when you print both results, the inlining is suppressed, and `baseC` and `baseR` get recalculated for every `bigManhattan` call on every element of `pairs`.  The simplest way to work around this is to move the `sum` and `map` into `bigManhattan` to ensure `baseC` and `baseR` only get calculated once per sum.  You could do even better, since they don't depend on `k` either, but this seems to work fast enough.

```
bigManhattan :: Int -> [Coord] -> [(Coord, Coord)] -> Int
bigManhattan k galaxies = sum . map go
  where
    baseC, baseR :: [Int]
    baseC = [0..(nSize-1)] \\ (fst <$> galaxies)
    baseR = [0..(nSize-1)] \\  (snd <$> galaxies)

    go ((c1,r1),(c2,r2)) = manhattan (c1+newc1, r1+newr1) (c2+newc2, r2+newr2)
      where newc1, newc2, newr1, newr2 :: Int
            newc1 = k * length (filter (c1>) baseC)
            newc2 = k * length (filter (c2>) baseC)
            newr1 = k * length (filter (r1>) baseR)
            newr2 = k * length (filter (r2>) baseR)


day11 :: IO ()
day11 = do
  ls <- getLines 11
  let galaxies = parse ls
      pairs = [(x,y) | x <- galaxies, y <- galaxies, x<y ]

  putStrLn $ "Day11: part1: " ++ show (bigManhattan 1 galaxies pairs)
  putStrLn $ "Day11: part2: " ++ show (bigManhattan 999999 galaxies pairs)
  return ()
```

Comment: Thanks. I've learnt something today.

Comment: nice! out of curiousity: is there an easy way to detect whether a function is inlined? or how did you come up with the solution?

Comment: I ended up inspecting the core (`ghc -fforce-recomp -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -dsuppress-uniques`), though there are also specific flags to show what's inlined during compliation (`-ddump-inlinings` and `-ddump-verbose-inlinings`).